# How to select records in SQL where one SKU has 2 or more of the same end date

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to pull out a list of items in a table which have more than 1 end date of 12/31/2100, as items should only have 1 (per price line). Here's the query I have so far:

```
SELECT PCL.*, SKUP.SKU_DESC,COUNT(CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE,PCL.DATEEND) = CONVERT(DATE,"12/31/2100")) AS [Count]
FROM PCL LEFT JOIN SKUP ON PCL.SKU = SKUP.SKU
WHERE PCL.PRICELINE = "R12-RETAILER"
GROUP BY PCL.SKU
WHERE [Count] > 1
```

PCL is the price table, just bringing in the SKUP table for the item descriptions.
When I run this query in Access, I get an error "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'COUNT(CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE,PCL.DATEEND) = CONVERT(DATE,"12/31/2100"))'."

Would someone be able to help me identify how this could be corrected or help point me toward an article which may better explain this?

I've been googling a lot this morning trying to find better examples for this specific application, but still learning a lot about the Group By and Count functions in SQL queries

Edit to describe my desired result, I'm just trying to pull out the records from the table which have 2+ of the date 12/31/2100, because there should only be 1 "ongoing" price for each item. If I can export it, I should be able to determine where the previous price should have ended based on the start dates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Access specifically but shouldn't this line:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE,PCL.DATEEND) = CONVERT(DATE,"12/31/2100"))
```

be something like:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE,PCL.DATEEND) = CONVERT(DATE,"12/31/2100" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
```

Comment: I just tried to paste it in (made a small change to close the 2nd Convert and put brackets around the 2 converts) but still didn't seem to work, I pasted this: `SUM(CASE WHEN (CONVERT(DATE,PCL.DATEEND) = CONVERT(DATE,"12/31/2100")) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))`

Comment: There's no `CASE WHEN` in Access. Use the *inline-if* function `IIF(condition, True, False)` and nest if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like

```
SELECT PCL.*, SKUP.SKU_DESC, COUNT(1)
FROM PCL LEFT JOIN SKUP ON PCL.SKU = SKUP.SKU
WHERE PCL.PRICELINE = "R12-RETAILER" AND PCL.DATEEND=#2100-12-31#
GROUP BY PCL.SKU
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

which I have not tested.

Note that it is possible to use date literals if you surround them with `#`.

Note that `WHERE` clause is filtering the result set before grouping, whereas `HAVING` is filtering the result set after grouping. Your query had two `WHERE` clauses which is not possible anyways.

`COUNT(1)` is just counting the number of records, to allow you to filter using `HAVING` clause.